# Dwarf Challenge - Team Effort

Tags: hero-academy

I've completed all of the challenges except for "Team Effort" (the fifth dwarf challenge), can someone tell me how to do this or at least give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint #1** - The Annihilator's attack causes adjacent units to move.

**Hint #2** - The Engineer's special ability is that she gets a larger boost from special squares.

**Full Solution**

> **Action #1** - Attack the Priestess with the Annihilator.  The Impaler will end up beside the bottom Paladin, while the Void Monk will end up beside the top Paladin.
>  **Action #2** - Attack the Impaler with the Paladin.
>  **Action #3** - Move the Engineer to the Assault Boost square.
>  **Actions #4 & #5** - Attack the Void Monk with the Engineer.